# Reconnect bluetooth device from the command line

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

After a while of using my bluetooth headphones, they sometimes build up latency and start to stutter. My manual solution is to disconnect and reconnect them, however, this quickly becomes annoying. How can I reconnect my headphones from using a script?

Answer (score 2):

The following script finds the first device in the computer's bluetooth device list, reconnects it, and switches the audio profile to the high quality A2DP profile. In some cases, it is not required to reconnect, but switching the audio profile from A2DP to HSP and back does the trick (commented out below).

```
#!/bin/sh

device=$(echo -e 'list' | bluetoothctl | grep Device)
name=$(echo $device | sed -n 's/.* [0-9A-C:]\{17\} \(.*\)/\1/p')
address=$(echo $device | awk '{ print $4; }')

echo "Disconnect $name ($device)"
echo -e "disconnect $address" | bluetoothctl
sleep 5

echo "Connect $name ($device)"
echo -e "connect $address" | bluetoothctl
sleep 5

card=$(pacmd list-cards | grep -oP 'name: <\K(bluez[^>]*)')

# echo "Switching $card to HSP"
# pacmd set-card-profile $card headset_head_unit
# sleep 1

echo "Switching $card to A2DP"
pacmd set-card-profile $card a2dp_sink
```

Comment: I use [pylover's a2dp.py script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae/raw/bbba417cae1419ed35b79c1ac400c7197a12e2fc/a2dp.py) for that